# Namespace/Mosaic Duration Limitations?

Tags: nem

are there any limit for setting duration for namespaces (and mosaics)?

I have tried with Long.MAX_VALUE, 100000, only 1000 succeeded in registering, then i have tried with an account with 20k testxems on it, and was able to set the duration of the namespace to 50k...

Based on the trial/error it is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catapult can be configured in regards to the Duration limit of the namespace in `config-network.properties` file by using this:

`maxNamespaceDuration = 365d`

The default is 365 days and here a link to the full content of the file:
[config-network.properties](https://github.com/nemtech/catapult-server/blob/76136e10ed2f3e74ffd6bd9791d8e69f50a63c32/resources/config-network.properties#L45)

Comment: just tested based on the day limit and blockGenerationTargetTime value in the config, and the highest duration is 2102400, if you have the enough tokens in your account... 2102401 is returning invalid duration exception on announce... thanks a lot for pointing out the config file.

Comment: your welcome :).. yes given that the block time is 15s then 2102400 / 4 / 60 / 24 = 365